# Angular UI grid sort a column through script

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

Is there any function available in grid API or any other way to sort a column from script instead of clicking on the header?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to turn on the auto-sort that clicking the header turns on through your script you can:

- Use `gridApi.grid.sortColumn()` (see http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:Grid) You have to pass `sortColumn()` a column object and a sort direction (either "asc" or "desc").
- After calling `sortColumn()`, you will probably need to call `gridApi.grid.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);` This is to refresh the presentation of data in the grid. Be sure to inject `uiGridConstants` into your controller/directive.
- Of course, for the above two calls, you will probably have `gridApi` as a property on `$scope`

If, instead, you want to do a one time sort of the grid on a given column (so that the auto-sorting does not remain enabled), you will have to sort the `gridOptions.data` array and then call `gridApi.grid.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL)`.

A library like underscore or lodash can really simplify the sorting of `gridOptions.data`.